# How to display the ROS message in the terminal?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
 notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.17
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 2 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - repo_name_hw2
-- ~~  - repo_uniquename_hw2
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'repo_name_hw2'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(repo_name_hw2)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- repo_name_hw2: 1 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'repo_uniquename_hw2'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(repo_uniquename_hw2)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target _repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_check_deps_test_custom_msg
[  0%] Built target _repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_check_deps_test_custom_msg
Scanning dependencies of target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_cpp
[ 14%] Generating C++ code from repo_name_hw2/test_custom_msg.msg
[ 14%] Built target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_cpp
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 14%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Generating Python from MSG repo_name_hw2/test_custom_msg
[ 42%] Generating Python msg __init__.py for repo_name_hw2
[ 42%] Built target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_py
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 42%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 57%] Generating Javascript code from repo_name_hw2/test_custom_msg.msg
[ 57%] Built target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_nodejs
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 57%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_eus
[ 71%] Generating EusLisp code from repo_name_hw2/test_custom_msg.msg
[ 85%] Generating EusLisp manifest code for repo_name_hw2
[ 85%] Built target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_eus
Scanning dependencies of target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 85%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_lisp
[100%] Generating Lisp code from repo_name_hw2/test_custom_msg.msg
[100%] Built target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages_lisp
Scanning dependencies of target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages
[100%] Built target repo_name_hw2_generate_messages
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosmsg show repo_name_hw2/Num
Unable to load msg [repo_name_hw2/Num]: Cannot locate message [Num]: unknown package [repo_name_hw2] on search path [{}]
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosmsg show Num
Could not find msg 'Num'
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.000001 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosmsg show repo_name_hw2/Num
Unable to load msg [repo_name_hw2/Num]: Cannot locate message [Num] in package [repo_name_hw2] with paths [['/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/src/repo_name_hw2/msg', '/home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/devel/share/repo_name_hw2/msg']]
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosmsg show Num
Could not find msg 'Num'
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosmsg show [string]
Could not find msg '[string]'
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosmsg show Num
Could not find msg 'Num'
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosmsg show Num
Could not find msg 'Num'
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ rosmsg show Num
Could not find msg 'Num'
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws$ cd /home/notsotechnical/catkin_ws/src
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosmsg show Num
Could not find msg 'Num'
notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src$ ros run repo_name_hw2

Command 'ros' not found, did you mean:

  command 'rocs' from snap rocs (19.08.0)
  command 'roo' from snap roo (2.0.3)
  command 'ro' from deb golang-redoctober
  command 'rs' from deb rs
  command 'rs' from deb reminiscence
  command 'rox' from deb rox-filer
  command 'rcs' from deb rcs
  command 'rows' from deb rows
  command 'rods' from deb raster3d
  command 'vos' from deb openafs-client
  command 'rocs' from deb rocs
  command 'bos' from deb openafs-client
  command 'eos' from deb elk-lapw

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.

notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src$ ros

Command 'ros' not found, did you mean:

  command 'roo' from snap roo (2.0.3)
  command 'rocs' from snap rocs (19.08.0)
  command 'rcs' from deb rcs
  command 'rs' from deb rs
  command 'rs' from deb reminiscence
  command 'rods' from deb raster3d
  command 'rox' from deb rox-filer
  command 'eos' from deb elk-lapw
  command 'bos' from deb openafs-client
  command 'ro' from deb golang-redoctober
  command 'vos' from deb openafs-client
  command 'rocs' from deb rocs
  command 'rows' from deb rows

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.

notsotechnical@notsotechnical-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333876/how-to-display-the-ros-message-in-the-terminal?/) by [notSoTechnical](https://answers.ros.org/users/46075/notsotechnical/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on 2019-09-25**:
Hi, can you please narrow down your question a little?
Instead of:

```
ros run repo_name_hw2
```

it should be (without blank between ros and run):

```
rosrun repo_name_hw2 node_name
```

To answer the question in the title:

```
rosmsg
```

can be helpful - see also [rosmsg page](https://wiki.ros.org/rosmsg)

Greetings!

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2019-09-25**:
Can you update your question with `CMakeLists.txt` from your `repo_name_hw2` package? Please only include lines that are not commented out. Also, please show the output of `rosls repo_name_hw2/msg/`. If you are using the same `CMakeLists.txt` from https://answers.ros.org/question/333844/how-to-create-a-string-message-in-a-ros-package-with-catkin-correctly/, then you are not telling catkin to generate headers for a `repo_name_hw2/Num` message type. The only message type built is `test_custom_msg.msg`.

Your bash output of `Generating C++ code from repo_name_hw2/test_custom_msg.msg` indicates that you are only building that message type. If you do a `rosmsg show repo_name_hw2/test_custom_msg` you should get valid output.

We will know more, and will probably be able to give an answer, with a little bit more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@krl101 : That's not totally correct, `rosrun` expects 2 arguments : `PACKAGE_NAME` and `EXECUTABLE_NAME` but I don't exactly see the point of what OP tried to do with that command.

@notSoTechnical : For the message, if it's correctly created, you have to give the package where the msg file is and the name of the msg file without the extension `.msg`, both separated by a `/` :

```
rosmsg show PACKAGE_NAME/NAME_OF_YOUR_MSG_FILE
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on 2019-09-25**:
@Delb yes, you are completely right. I just corrected it.
OP tried this command without success